# Specify static text value in a ContentControl with a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating an application that will be used to edit a lot of product specifications in a single window.

I have a bunch of dimensions (in inches) and I want to create a simple template that will show, for each dimension, the value both as a fraction and as a decimal value.
It's basically a TextBlock, and two TextBox.

[image: inches control UI]

But I can't figure how to specify the text of the TextBlock (in this case Width).
I would like to be able to specify it in the ContentControl declaration (or something similar).

Here's my DataTemplate :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InchesInputTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /> <!-- How should I define the binding ? -->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Content, Converter=InchesToFractionConverter}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Content}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then I use it in a ContentControl :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Width}" 
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InchesInputTemplate}"
                LabelText="Width :" />
```

And my simplified Product class (it will contain many more dimensions) :

```
public class Product
{
    private string _productCode;

    public string ProductCode
    {
        get { return _productCode; }
        set { _productCode = value; }
    }

    private float _width;

    public float Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set { _width = value; }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to specify the text of the Label for each of my dimensions (LabelText property in my example) ?

Comment: Where is the Inches property that you're binding to? Is the float Width property not the same one that you're binding to Content? If you were passing a complex object (with an Inches property) as Content you could just add more properties onto that and bind to them inside the template.

Comment: @John Bowen You're right, I made a mistake here.  I wanted to have a complex object for my dimensions at first but I realized it wasn't needed.  I corrected the binding expression.

Comment: That makes more sense but the new bindings are needlessly complex. The parent control's Content is already the DataContext in the template so you can just use {Binding Converter=InchesToFractionConverter}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Tag` property

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InchesInputTemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=Tag}" />
    <!--  How should I define the binding ?  -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Inches, Converter=InchesToFractionConverter}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Inches}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Width}" 
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InchesInputTemplate}"
                Tag="Width :" />
```

**Update:**

If you do not want to use the `Tag` property, you could use an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx):

```
public class MyLabelPropertyClass {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyLabelTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "MyLabelText",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(MyLabelPropertyClass),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

  public static void SetMyLabelText(UIElement element, string value) {
    element.SetValue(MyLabelTextProperty, value);
  }

  public static string GetMyLabelText(UIElement element) {
    return (string)element.GetValue(MyLabelTextProperty);
  }
}
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InchesInputTemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:MyLabelPropertyClass.MyLabelText), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
...
</DataTemplate>
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Width}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InchesInputTemplate}"
                local:MyLabelPropertyClass.MyLabelText="Width :" />
```

**Alternate**

If you want to subclass `ContentControl` with a normal [Dependency property](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html):

```
public class MyCustomContentControl : ContentControl {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyLabelTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "MyLabelText",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(MyCustomContentControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

  public string MyLabelText {
    get {
      return (string)GetValue(MyLabelTextProperty);
    }
    set {
      SetValue(MyLabelTextProperty, value);
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InchesInputTemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyLabelText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyCustomContentControl}}}" />
...
</DataTemplate>
...
<local:MyCustomContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InchesInputTemplate}"
                              MyLabelText="Width :" />
```

Comment: Thanks ! Good idea, it would work, but I prefer to avoid the use of the Tag.  I may still use it if it's really the best way to solve this problem (but I hope there's a more natural and WPF way to do it).

Comment: @igelineau Well it's the quickest but if you do not want to use the `Tag` property then you could use an Attached property(I've updated my answer with an example). If you want even further distinction, subclass `ContentControl` and add a Dependency Property to it.

Comment: Subclassing ContentControl with a Dependency Property is interesting, it seems to be the cleaner way to go so far.  I'l probably try this after the weekend.  Thanks !

Comment: @igelineau I updated my answer with the subclass method as well.